# How can use nested if for multiple select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello everyone I'm trying to do when user select an option, another option will appear. Yes, I did it but when user select other options, I wanna display text but it does not work here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".select-box").change(function() {
          if ($(".select-box option[value='3']").attr('selected')) {
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="<select class='select-box'><option value='4'>a</option><option value='5'>b</option></select>";
          if ($(".select-box option[value='5']").attr('selected')) {
          document.write("Hello")
          }
          }

        }); 

      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select class="select-box">
      <option>Select an option</option>
      <option value="1">no alert</option>
      <option value="2">no alert too</option>
      <option value="3">alert</option>
    </select> 
    <p></br>
    <div id="demo"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what exactly do you want? when should be your 'Hello' written?

Comment: You don't have an option with a value of 5 like the second if is looking for.

Comment: When youu click alert option, another option appears that has option values "a" and "b" then when you click b option it will display "Hello"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use jQuery's `on()` function, since you want to add eventhandler to the second select, which is added to the DOM dynamically.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#main').on('change', '.select-box', function() {

        if ($(this).val() == 3) {
            $('#demo').html("<select class='select-box'><option value='4'>a</option><option value='5'>b</option></select>");
        }

        if ($(this).val() == 5) {
            alert("Hello");
        }
    });

});​
```

See the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gju5q/1).

I have wrapped your element with a div and attached  the change handler to it.

Also notice, that I have replaced your javascript `getElementById` with jQuery selectors, and I have simplified your value checks.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work as at the moment when the script is running there is only one element in the DOM matching selector `.select-box`. So after creating the second one, you have to bind the event listener one more time.

Comment: I suggested the theoretical part of solution, but Michal's answer is the pratical implementation of what I said, so use it.